# How to await async operations / coroutines?

Tags: c#, unity, multithreading, coroutines

I'm looking for a generic / reusable way to wait for coroutines and asynchronous operations to finish in Unity 5, similiar to C#5's `await` keyword.

The simplest way I can think of is something like this:

```
 public class SomeUtility {
     public bool IsDoingSomething { get; private set; }

     public IEnumerator DoSomethingAsync() {
         IsDoingSomething = true;
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
         IsDoingSomething = false;
     }
 }
```

and then in another coroutine:

```
 while(!someUtilityInstance.IsDoingSomething)
     yield return null;
```

However this is not very nice because it clutters the code with `while` statements, is not reusable (needs instances and dedicated classes even for simple utility functions!) and a lot of singleton or static stuff where it's not even needed.

The closest I found is using Unity's `AsyncOperation`. This here works very nicely:

```
public static IEnumerator Await(this AsyncOperation operation) {
    while(!operation.isDone)
        yield return operation;
}

yield return SceneManager.LoadLevelAsync("blaaaah").Await();
```

However.. the problem is: How to create an `AsyncOperation`? A few services, for examples `SceneManager` are using it, but the documentation completely lacks anything about creating custom operations or wrapping existing coroutines etc.

So, is there a way to create a simple, generic and resuable "await" for custom coroutines?

Comment: Perhaps use reflection and callbacks? Pass two methods into a coroutines. The first one the method to do. Use reflection to see when it finishes, then call the second one

Answer (score 2):

```
yield return StartCoroutine(yourIEnumatorMethod());
```

Will wait until your method has completed, the only inconvenient with that solution is it forces you to make this call within an `IEnumator` method.

See http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html

Answer (score 0):

With Unity 2017 you can now use async await as an alternative to coroutines as [described here](http://www.stevevermeulen.com/index.php/2017/09/23/using-async-await-in-unity3d-2017/)

Comment: Link is not working